# Codeigniter and redirect old url's

Tags: codeigniter, url, redirect, hyperlink, routes

I have designed and developed new version of a website in codeigniter.
The old one was in pure php.Now i want to route or redirect the old links that are registered in google or other place to new site and correct url's.

My few old URLs are

> domain.com/en
>   domain.com/en/article.html

Now i want to redirect my all url to

> domain.com
>   domain.com/en/submit
>   domain.com/home/articles/2055

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use proper links that hit the controller methods to go to appropriate pages.
For example let suppose you had a page in your website built with php.

```
article.html
```

So you must have a controller now to load the article.php as view. For example

```
class Home Extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function articles(){
        //get id with get , post or segment
        //$data['article'] = //get article from database on the base of id
        $this->load->view('article',$data);//load article.php from application/views
    }
}
```

In articles method in your php website you may be getting article id through get or post here you can use `get` , `post` or `segment`.
Use `site_url('home/article')` or `base_url()` in the views. For example

```
$id =   2055;
site_url('home/article'.$id);
```